# How do I get this SQL query?

Tags: sql, join, database-design

The models are:

```
Group {
    Id : int
}

Item {
    GroupId : int
    Status : int
}
```

How do I make query for this output table:

```
GroupID | TotalItemCount | ItemsWithStatus = 1 | ItemsWithStatus = 2
```

Comment: "models".  Databases have tables and columns.  Also, MySQL and SQL Server are very different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
select g.groupid, count(*) as numitems,
       sum(case when i.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as status_1,
       sum(case when i.status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as status_2
from items i join
     groups g
     on i.groupid = g.id
group by g.groupid;
```